# URL rewrite rule not working in Visual Studio Development Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, url-rewriting

How can I troubleshoot url rewrite rules that are not working in my Visual Studio 2010 Development environment?

I am enhancing an existing ASP.NET application.

My issue is the URL rewrite rules written in web.config do not work in my Visual Studio 2010 development environment. It only works after deploying the project to IIS.

I need to debug the project as I am not familiar with how it is designed and developed. It is too big a project.

If rewrite won't work in the Visual Studio Development Server, is there a workaround? I really need to work on the project in debug mode. Every time it takes me to a custom error page.

Comment: give some details to us which will help us to go close to the issue, show some code or relevant data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always debug into your local IIS. There are 3 approaches:

- You should be able to do this seamlessly if your project is configured to deploy to the local IIS web server - just hit F5. It should deploy then attach.
- After you deploy, browse to the local site, then attach to the running site by using "Debug, Attach to Process, w3wp.exe".
- Add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` to the line on which you want to break your code, deploy to IIS, then run. A "start debugging" dialog should appear when the line is hit.

Answer (score 1):

URL Rewrite does not work on the built in web server used by Visual Studio.  The good news is that you can absolutely debug the site easily using a local install of IIS.  See the following blog entry for details on how to do this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

I would strongly suggest going the route of IIS Express (a quick web search will get you to the download page) that Scott recommends.  I tried setting VS up to use my local IIS 7 and struggled with it.  When I tried the IIS Express route, I was up and running in minutes with URL Rewrite working nicely in my dev environment - no need to manually attach to anything.  After installing IIS Express, I just had to go into the site properties->"Web" tab->"Servers" heading->select "Use Local IIS Web server" and check "Use IIS Express".

Answer (score 0):

If you create an IIS website on your local machine then rewrite should work.
If you don't have IIS installed I think you can download it using the MS Web Platform Installer.

I'm not sure if the debugger will work in this situation, but at least you don't have to deploy to a remote machine to test your changes.

Comment: Add the local IIS via Windows Features via Programs in Control Panel, then add URL Rewriting via WebPI.